# What's the translation of a “breakthrough infection" in French?

Tags: traduction, santé-et-médecine

From https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/over-86-per-cent-of-breakthrough-infections-caused-by-delta-variant-icmr/article35367198.ece ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210724080440/https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/over-86-per-cent-of-breakthrough-infections-caused-by-delta-variant-icmr/article35367198.ece)):

> A **breakthrough infection** is a case of illness in which a vaccinated individual becomes sick from the same illness that the vaccine is meant to prevent.

What's the translation of a “breakthrough infection" in French?

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=breakthrough%20infection&op=translate) didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un infection post-vaccinale :

> Par définition, une infection post-vaccinale survient lorsqu’un individu est trouvé positif à un test PCR ou antigénique réalisé sur un prélèvement respiratoire effectué après un délai égal ou supérieur à 14 jours après injection de la seconde dose de vaccin.

[Le Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/blog/realitesbiomedicales/2021/05/05/covid-19-infections-post-vaccinales-dues-a-des-variants/)